# How to set up Microsoft Sync trace listener

Tags: c#, synchronization, trace, microsoft-sync-framework

For some reason I'm getting a "Failed to execute the command 'BulkInsertCommand' for table" and the error is caused by "Operand type clash: bigint is incompatible with uniqueidentifier" but I would think this can't be, because the fields in the database wouldn't allow the wrong input to begin with.  I'm not sure if setting up a trace listener is going to help but at this point I can't see any other information about this error.

I'm trying to set up a sync listener but I can't find any information on how to set it up right, even on the Microsoft page where it says "**Complete Code Example**" and yet there is no code.

This is how I've set up listeners before.  What do I need to change for it to listen to sync?

C#

```
private static readonly TraceSource ClientTraceSource = new TraceSource("ClientTraceSource");
```

web.config

```
    <system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4" />
<sources>
  <source name="ClientTraceSource" switchValue="Error,Information" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
    <listeners>
      <add name="myListener" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="myListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="XMLValidationErrorLog.txt" traceOutputOptions="DateTime">
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
```

Comment: have you changed datatypes after you provisioned the scope? you can check the user defined table type for your table to see what datatype is in there vs what's in your table. you can also open the scope_config table to see how your scope was defined.

Comment: There was no change to the schema.  user defined table type looks to be good.  There are 3 scope configs in xml format which I'll look at next.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the mappings and tracer is not recording anything from sync activities.  This is what I placed only in the config file  <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
      --><!-- Sync Tracer Setting 0-off, 1-error, 2-warn, 3-info, 4-verbose. --><!--
      <add name="SyncTracer" value="4" />
    </switches>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <clear/>
        <add name="TestSyncListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="SyncTraceFile.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>

Comment: try this:   <switches>
      <add name="DefaultSwitch" value="Information" />
      <!-- Sync Tracer Setting 0-off, 1-error, 2-warn, 3-info, 4-verbose. -->
      <add name="SyncTracer" value="4" />
    </switches>

    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add name="TestSyncListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="c:\SyncTraceFile.txt" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>